# How to select random samples in a dataframe?

Tags: r

I am using the following command to create 50 random samples in a dataset.
and I want to know the mean of observations(area).

```
ds1 %>%
  sample_n(size = 50) %>%
  summarise(x_bar = mean(area))
```

But I get

```
Error in function_list[[i]](value) : could not find function "sample_n"
```

I tried searching for the function sample_n using getAnywhere() but I didn't find the object.

Instead it works when I use,

```
ds1_samp3 <- 
  ames[sample(nrow(ds1), 1000), ]

ds1_samp3 %>% 
  summarise(mu = mean(area))
```

Just want to know why the first command doesn't work?

Thanks,
Vkva

Answer (score 1):

`sample_n` is contained in the `dplyr` package. It will work as long as you have installed & imported said package in your session. Substituting with `sample` (from base) will not work because it does not assume `data.frame` input, whereas `sample_n` does.

Answer (score 0):

`sample_n` is not a function in R. Use `sample` instead:

```
ds1 %>%
  sample(size = 50) %>%
  summarise(x_bar = mean(area))
```